# Separate ten random training and testing data set

Tags: r

I am trying to separate my dataset into ten different pairs of random training(50%) and testing(50%) data set. The following is my R code:
`

```
n_all = nrow(data3)
set.seed(1)
train_all_1 = sample(1:n_all,0.5*n_all,replace = FALSE)
traindata_1 = data3[train_all_1,]
testdata_1 = data3[-train_all_1,]
set.seed(2)
train_all_2 = sample(1:n_all,0.5*n_all,replace = FALSE) 
traindata_2 = data3[train_all_2,]
testdata_2 = data3[-train_all_2,]
```

`
...
keep going.... until 10. I wonder if there's another way to do this by using any package or function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be helpful

```
train.test <- function(seed=NULL, data){
  if(!is.null(seed)){set.seed(seed)}
  train_all <-sample(1:n_all,0.5*n_all,replace = FALSE)
  output <- list(traindata=data[train_all,],
                 testdata=data[-train_all,])
  return(output)
}
```

As you can see `train.test` returns a list consisting of `traindata` and  `testdata`

```
lapply(1:10, function(i) train.test(seed=i, data=data3))
```

You can also use `replicate`

```
set.seed(1); replicate(10, train.test(data=data3), simplify = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use replicate with `simplify` parameter set to `FALSE`:

```
data <- head(iris,10)
n_all = nrow(data)
set.seed(1)
datasets <- replicate(3,data[sample(1:n_all,0.5*n_all,replace = FALSE),],simplify = F)
# [[1]]
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
# 8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
# 
# [[2]]
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
# 2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
# 1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 
# [[3]]
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
# 7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
# 3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: what is the parameter simplify = F means?

Comment: when simplify is `TRUE` the function will check the format of the output and if it's possible, will try to simplify it, in our case it sees 3 need tables of the same size and will concat them. With simplify = FALSE you make sure you get lists